# Test question with the word "effect"

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

I was practicing IELTS tests and got this one:

> The accident has a ... effect on her.

1. Effective
2. Focusing
3. Total
4. Wide

I was thinking "wide" is the correct choice here, but it was "total" instead.

I can't understand why. I searched Google for "have a total effect on somebody" and found nothing.

The test question is from the "adjectives" section of the Android app called IELTS Test Pro 2018 that has the text IELTS and a green arrow pointing upward on its icon.

Comment: Bad test question.  I think **focusing** is the best answer. And **has** is not the right tense.  I mean, like, it's totally wrong. Totally.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo It comes from the android application called IELTS. Why "focusing"? I thought "wide".

Comment: I agree with @Tᴚoɯɐuo. *Focusing* is the one I would have chosen, and the present tense clanked in my ear.

Comment: Also agree with @Tᴚoɯɐuo. Wrong tense with *has* and in this construction only _focusing_ or _wide_ could be considered possible valid answers. There are many apps called "IELTS < something >" for Android but I don't see anything just called "IELTS". Unfortunately there are many low-quality apps out there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - as pointed out by many others - ***it's a terrible test question!***

Comment: I am voting to leave this question open, because the poor quality of the text question notwithstanding the OP's question is a legit one for English learners. And the question deserves examination and answering.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's not my fault it is.

Comment: Obviously not. But are you suggesting all closevotes must somehow imply criticism of the questioner? My only criterion here is *Is this question likely to be useful to future visitors?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Looks to me as though the explanation of exactly why the test is terrible is actually helpful in itself.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I certainly agree with that! And I would *never* vote to "Delete" this question *for that very reason*. One of the problems is that many "English Tests" on the Internet are created by people who aren't even native Anglophones (let alone competent test-setters). But how is your average learner supposed to know the difference between a *meaningful* "test" and absolute drivel? At least if they see things like this (even if "Closed") question, it's a reminder that if they can't see / understand an unambiguously correct answer, it might just be *because there isn't one*.

Comment: But obviously if I knew that the test-setter expected me to come up with the single "correct" selection, I'd be pretty confident about plumping for ***focusing*** (Though being an older Brit myself, I might just say it should be spelt ***focussing*** anyway! :)

Answer (score 3):

That's a terrible test question!

It can't be (1) because the article is wrong. You would have to use "an" with "effective". Saying an "effective effect" is rather clunky writing, but not inherently wrong.

But the other 3 are all possible.

I'd say (2) is the best choice, because it is both grammatically valid and makes the most logical sense.

A "focusing effect" makes sense. The accident caused her to become more focused in her thinking.

A "total effect" doesn't make sense in this context. Total of what? You could say, "The total effect of the accident was that it made her more cautious" or some such. But to say it had a "total effect", what does that mean?

A "wide effect" is possible but awkward. It could mean that if affected many things. But a fluent speaker would be more likely to say, "a broad effect".

So I'd say (2) is the best choice and (4) is possible. (1) is wrong and (3) is unlikely.

How anyone could say that (3) is correct and (2) and (4) are wrong is just ... baffling.

Comment: I think the tense chosen does not make sense either; besides, I'd rather use *profound, important, powerful, or strong* to collocate them, in this case, with *effect*.

Comment: @Ustanak Oh, I agree about the verb tense. Others mentioned it in the comments so I didn't see a need to bring it up myself. And yes, there are certainly many other words that could fit in the sentence, many words that would be better than "total" or "wide".

Comment: or a *far-reaching* effect.  **wide** doesn't cut it for me.

Comment: @Jay: Generally anything worth explaining about the English in play should make it into an answer, even if the comments already skimmed it, since we shouldn't rely on comments to carry the explanations.